# The relationship between formal power series and power series (analytic) in their convergence domain?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ be the ring of formal power series. Operations and properties have been defined (as commonly seen in textbooks).

For each $A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n {X}^n$ belonging to $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$, we define a function
$S: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ determined by
$$\tilde{A}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n {x}^n,$$
where $\mathbb{D}=\{x \in \mathbb{C} \mid |x| \le R\}$ with $R$ being the convergence radius of the power series (analytic) $\tilde{A}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n {x}^n$.

My question is: When I apply the properties of formal power series, including coefficient extraction, and then apply them to the power series $\tilde{A}(x)$, do all the properties remain preserved, or is this merely a similarity (as we observe and perceive), or is it a theorem or property? Please provide me with any information, articles, or explanations. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "all the properties." If the radius of convergence is nonzero then various basic facts about Taylor series imply e.g. that this map is additive and multiplicative, that kind of thing.